# Firebase listener is blocked in Java(Android)

Tags: java, android, websocket, firebase

I have a simple `onChildAdded` listener set, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
listRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot,
            String previousChildName) {

        Log.d("DEBUG","A child has been added!");
        // Do stuff...

    }
    // Other unimplemented methods for ChildEventListener here...
});

while(true);
```

I'm adding children to listRef but nothing happens.

The `while(true)` line is here on purpose to demonstrate my problem, which is that the handler is only able to fire after everything else finishes! And in this case, it never does. When I remove this line it works.

I assume that this is by design. Is there any way to make it work in these situations regardless of what comes after?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while(true)` would permanently block the thread from receiving events, since the Android client uses the main thread to post events.

It is possible to set a different thread to receive events via [Config.setEventTarget()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Config.html#setEventTarget%28com.firebase.client.EventTarget%29)

In this case, the EventTarget is passed instances of Runnable which it is responsible for running to receive events.